# Getting Session XML Variable After Redirection

Tags: php, xml, session, redirect

I created an XML using SimpleXMLElement and its asXML() function. I set this XML to a session variable. So once this is done, I used the header redirection to another php file and tried to use the session xml. However it's empty! I know that there are some other session variables that I also set, and there are not empty. The only empty session variable is XML. Why is this?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

The most likely culprit is you are either not initializing the session either when you are writing the data, or reading the data.

See [session_start()](http://php.net/session_start)

Providing the relevant code would also be useful.